# Equilibrium position for double spring hanging vertically

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, equilibrium

I feel a bit daft asking this but how do you calculate the equilibrium position of a system with a spring  (spring constant *k1*) hanging from the ceiling with a mass (*m1*) attached to the bottom, and attached to *m1*, there is another spring with spring constant *k2* which is attached at the bottom to a mass *m2*.
I know how to calculate the motion with the Lagrangian and Newtonian approach, but I wish to know how to calculate the extension of the spring in equilibrium position given the spring constants and masses.
Supposing *m2* was not present then I can just equate the forces of the *m1*g with the *k1*x1 and solve for x1. But when I add a second mass to spring two, spring one also will stretch right? So I cannot equate *m2*g with *k2*x2 since there will be a force component from spring 1 also right? So how do I solve this problem? Is the weight of the spring distributed equally among the two springs? Or is it some other ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only force pulling $m_2$ up is the tension in spring $k_2$ (as you should be able to see by drawing a free body diagram). $m_1$ on the other hand is pulled up by tension in spring 1, but pulled down by tension in spring 2. The equations are
$$k_1\Delta x_1 = m_1 g + k_2\Delta x_2$$
$$k_2\Delta x_2 = m_2 g$$